# using django-waffle flags with google app engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I just installed django-waffle to my app that's running on google app engine. But when I try to manage my flags from the command line using the `manage.py` wrapper, I get this error:

`AssertionError: No api proxy found for service "memcache"`

Any ideas for how to manage this?